# how to populate nested object of an mongoose collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, populate

I am working on question and answer website working on its RESTful API, I stack on this problem. If anyone helps me I will be thankful I am new in Node.js and Express.js.

This is the MongoDB questions schema:

```js
const QuestionSchema = new Schema({
  slug: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: { type: String, required: true },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  category: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Category",
  },
  bookmarked: Boolean,
  comments: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Comment",
  },
});
```

This is an example of data:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ef8c312731f9c10f407defb"),
    "slug" : "question2",
    "title" : "چه نام‌هایی باعث افزایش برکت در خانه می‌شوند؟",
    "body" : "لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ، و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است، چاپگرها و متون بلکه روزنامه و مجله در ستون و سطرآنچنان که لازم است، و برای شرایط فعلی تکنولوژی مورد نیاز، و کاربردهای متنوع با هدف بهبود ابزارهای کاربردی می باشد، کتابهای زیادی در شصت و سه درصد گذشته حال و آینده، شناخت فراوان جامعه و متخصصان را می طلبد، تا با نرم افزارها شناخت بیشتری را برای طراحان رایانه ای علی الخصوص طراحان خلاقی، و فرهنگ پیشرو در زبان فارسی ایجاد کرد، در این صورت می توان امید داشت که تمام و دشواری موجود در ارائه راهکارها، و شرایط سخت تایپ به پایان رسد و زمان مورد نیاز شامل حروفچینی دستاوردهای اصلی، و جوابگوی سوالات پیوسته اهل دنیای موجود طراحی اساسا مورد استفاده قرار گیرد.",
    "date" : "28/june/2020",
    "status" : "1",
    "bookmarked" : false,
    "category" :ObjectId("5ef8be8204fe40030cf911ef"),
    "author" : ObjectId("5ef8bcf63f2b47099ca117ef"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "comments" : [ 
        ObjectId("5ef8c44423f04831e41f14d3"), 
        ObjectId("5ef8c46323f04831e41f14d4"), 
        ObjectId("5ef8c52f2ffd6929e09d10dd"), 
        ObjectId("5ef8c52f2ffd6929e09d10de"), 
        ObjectId("5ef8c5302ffd6929e09d10df"), 
        ObjectId("5ef8c57b2ffd6929e09d10e0"), 
        ObjectId("5ef8c5852ffd6929e09d10e1")
    ]
}
```

And this is server side get all questions code:

```js
// Route to get all questions
app.get("/questions", function (req, res) {
  db.Question.find({})
    .populate("author category comments")
    .then(function (dbQuestions) {
      res.json(dbQuestions);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      res.json(err);
    });
});
```

In response, I am not get all Questions Comments data only it shows the first element of comment array like this:

```js
{
        "_id": "5ef8c312731f9c10f407defb",
        "slug": "question2",
        "title": "چه نام‌هایی باعث افزایش برکت در خانه می‌شوند؟",
        "body": "لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ، و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است، چاپگرها و متون بلکه روزنامه و مجله در ستون و سطرآنچنان که لازم است، و برای شرایط فعلی تکنولوژی مورد نیاز، و کاربردهای متنوع با هدف بهبود ابزارهای کاربردی می باشد، کتابهای زیادی در شصت و سه درصد گذشته حال و آینده، شناخت فراوان جامعه و متخصصان را می طلبد، تا با نرم افزارها شناخت بیشتری را برای طراحان رایانه ای علی الخصوص طراحان خلاقی، و فرهنگ پیشرو در زبان فارسی ایجاد کرد، در این صورت می توان امید داشت که تمام و دشواری موجود در ارائه راهکارها، و شرایط سخت تایپ به پایان رسد و زمان مورد نیاز شامل حروفچینی دستاوردهای اصلی، و جوابگوی سوالات پیوسته اهل دنیای موجود طراحی اساسا مورد استفاده قرار گیرد.",
        "date": "28/june/2020",
        "status": "1",
        "bookmarked": false,
        "category": {
        "_id": "5ef8be8204fe40030cf911ef",
        "title": "زکات",
        "__v": 0
        },
        "author": {
        "_id": "5ef8bcf63f2b47099ca117ef",
        "firstName": "خالد",
        "lastName": "صمدی",
        "userAvatar": "./images/avatars/2.jpg",
        "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0,
            "comments": {  //here is showing only single element of array 
            "_id": "5ef8c44423f04831e41f14d3",
            "Body": "شرح نظریه اینجا نویشته میگردد که دارای متن مفصل میباشد",
            "author": "5ef8bd2e3f2b47099ca117f0",
            "date": "20/10/2020",
            "__v": 0
            }
}
```

I hope to get my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you're missing:

```
comments: [{
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: "Comment",
}],
```

The reference needs to be wrapped in `[]` to tell Mongoose that this is an array of comments, not a single comment.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in the schema you defined.
Since you are going to store array of ObjectID, mention the schema also in an array..

Replace "comments" definition with this. It will work.

```
comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comment", }]
```